# Humans and reptillian aliens had a war, after it ended the humans bred the aliens to become giant fighting dragons

Tags: story-identification, aliens, dragons

The put saddles on the dragons, wore armor and fought in tournament type battles. The dragons were not sentient and were only used in the sport.

One day the aliens returned and they, too, had taken prisoners (humans). They bred these humans to be muscle-bound cargo haulers. I believe other things as well.

Book had to be published in 1985 or older if that narrows it down any.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like it could be "The Dragon Masters", a classic novella by [Jack Vance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Vance). Amazon's [blurb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/141650494X) says:

> And so at last there came to be two neighboring worlds: Aerlith, where men have raised a race of fearsome dragons to be their servants, and nearby Coralyne, where the descendants of those very dragons are served by strong, savage mutants who once were human.

It has been reprinted [many, many times](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11826).

Comment: Jack Vance is a hell of an author. I think I'll look that book up for giggles.